# Compare columns of two dataframes with custom functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following two `dataframes`:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'unicorn': ['blue', 'red', 'piNk'], 'size': [3, 4, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'unicorn': ['red'], 'size': [2]})
```

df1:

```
  unicorn  size
0    blue     3
1     red     4
2    piNk     6
```

df2 (always has one row):

```
  unicorn  size
0     red     2
```

How can I compare the rows of both `dataframes` column-wise using custom comparison functions like this (simplified):

```py
def unicorn_comparison(str1, str2) -> float:
  return 100.0 if str1 == str2 else 0.0
```

and

```py
def size_comparison(nr1, nr2) -> float:
  return 100.0 if nr1 < nr2 else 0.0
```

Expected result:

```py
   unicorn  size
0      0.0   0.0
1    100.0   0.0
2      0.0   0.0
```

Comment: what if there are more rows in df2? can you update your example? Can you give more details on the "real-life" function, can it be vectorized?

Comment: Updated answer. Regarding the "real-life" functions: each function always compares exactly two variables and returns a float score.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification, I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70864248/16343464), however know that double looping with a custom function can be **very slow**. To optimize this, please try to give a more meaningful example of what the custom function really does

Comment: Updated answer to show that I am working with multiple functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have always a single row in df2, **don't use a DataFrame (2D), but a Series (1D)**.

```
ser = df2.loc[0]
```

Then assuming you just want a comparison, use vectorial code (not a custom function):

```
out = df1.eq(ser)*100
```

If you really need to use a non-vectorial function and have to compare all combinations, use:

```
def unicorn_comparison(str1, str2) -> float:
    return 100.0 if str1 == str2 else 0.0

def size_comparison(nr1, nr2) -> float:
    return 100.0 if nr1 < nr2 else 0.0

funcs = {'unicorn': unicorn_comparison,
         'size': size_comparison
        }

out = df1.apply(lambda c: c.apply(lambda s: funcs[c.name](s, ser[c.name])))
```

output:

```
   unicorn  size
0        0     0
1      100     0
2        0     0
```

Comment: Thank you. Just wondering how efficient this would be with multiple custom functions?

Comment: @DeepLearningEel I updated the code for multiple functions. I don't know how many cols/rows you have, nor what the functions are really doing, so I cannot really answer regarding the speed. You should give us feedback ;)

Comment: I have at most 8 rows in `df1`. Love the solution. Thanks!

Comment: And at most 6 columns.

Comment: Then it should be pretty fast, unless your comparison functions are themselves very slow ;)

Answer (score 0):

its way.
first; add df2's column of you want.

```
df1['unicorn2'] = df2['unicorn']
```

after; You can use "application loop". You can run the logic of the you want in the "application loop".

```
def function(x):
    # your logic
  return x
df1_result = df1.apply(function)
```

Comment: What about the rest of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in df1:
    df1[col] = (df1[col] == df2[col].loc[0]).replace({True: 100, False: 0})
```

This will overwrite your `df1`, or you can make a copy of it first.